# Subspace and Dimension

Tags: vector-spaces, solution-verification, contest-math

Suppose $W$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{​R}^n$ of dimension $d$. Show that

$|\{(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)) \in W : x_i \in {0,1}\}| \leq 2^d$

**Context:** This was a question from a 2019 Math contest. However, I am having difficulties on how to prove it. Thus, any help is appreciated.

**Attempt**
As the dimension of the subspace is $d$, hence we can write:

$W = span(e_1,e_2,...,e_d)$
Since, $x_i \in {0,1}$ so $e_i \in {0,1}$   thus, we can have $2^d$ such possible combinations for the basis.
Now I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: I think there is an issue with your notation : the subspace W has basis of size d, but I think using the notation "$x_i$" to denote it is a bad idea

Comment: @FimePr editted the attempt.

Comment: What do you mean by $e_i \in 0, 1$ ? The element $e_i$ is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$, right ?